# How to clear form control?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I have modified a validate method of form control. On this control I'm typing the product name. 
In validate method I'm checking if this product name exists in the table. If it does not exists the error is thrown.

My issue is that after the error is thrown I want to clear control. Here is my code:

```
public boolean validate()
{
    InventTable inventTable;
    boolean ret = super();
    select inventTable
        where inventTable.nameAlias == this.text();    
    if (!inventTable.recid)
    {
        error("error");
        this.text("");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

`this.text("");` does not work. So how can I clear the control? The control is a field from my datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In validate methods you do not need to clear the field. The system does that for you when `validate` returns false.

So instead of `this.text(''))` just `return false`.

But I doubt that the idea of users entering the full name is really useful at all.

If you use `NameAlias` as an alternate item number an even easier option exist.
Change the [AliasFor](http://gotdax.blogspot.dk/2010/11/aliasfor-property-on-tablefield.html) property on the `InventTable.NameAlias` field to point to `ItemId`.
When entering in an *ItemId* and you enter a `NameAlias` instead, it is translated to the corresponding item id by the AX run-time. This happens everywhere an item id is entered *and validated*.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.
One more question... if I have several controls and all of them are filled except the last one, then how can I clear all controls if the last one throws error?

Comment: Controls should not throw. The answer depends on whether your controls are bound (to table fields) or not. Bound controls are easy, just set the values of your table buffer, then call `refresh`.